# When I parse the date "03/12/2009 19:12 PM" with format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a" it return true

Tags: scala, date

val dateFormat = DateUtils.parseDateStrictly("03/12/2009 19:12 PM","MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a")

"03/12/2009 **19:12 *PM***" the input date is not valid with 12 hour date format **"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a"** but it returns date object

how to resolve this

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library, but the docs suggest that parseDateStrictly returns a Date object by design: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#parseDateStrictly(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HH` is the format marker for 24h hours.
Try `hh` instead, e.g.

```
val dateFormat = DateUtils.parseDateStrictly("03/12/2009 19:12 PM","MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a")
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: yeah right but this is not a valid date "03/12/2009 19:12 PM" need exception for unsupported date

Comment: @ravistondhanasekar It is a perfectly valid to add the am/pm suffix to a 24-hour time. If you don't want to allow this format, just make the change from `HH` to `hh`.